# Simple For Looping an Array

Tags: java, arrays

Below is part of the solution to an homework assignment I had, and I don't know why he has two for loops. If it was me, I would have set if (carsParked[i] == c) then set carsParked[i]=null
I don't understand why second for loop statement can anyone explain?
By the way, CarsParked array is a type of Car class which stores car objects that are parked.

```
public void driveOut(Car c)
{
    for (int i=0; i<carsParked.length; i++) // Loop through the carParked array
    {
        if(carsParked[i] == c) // Find Car c at index i
        {
            //carsParked, remove(c);
            for (int j=i; j<carsIn-1; j++)
            {
                carsParked[j] = carsParked[j+1];
            }
            carsParked[carsIn-1] = null; 
            carsIn = carsIn - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how cars are parked

```
public void driveIn(Car c)
{
    if(carsIn < carsParked.length)
    {
        carsParked[carsIn] = c;
        carsIn = carsIn + 1;
    }
    else // error message
    {
         System.out.println("Park " + location + " is full, for " + c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we suppose to read your mind to know what the assignment was? Or reverse engineer it from the answer?

Comment: i dont know what your question is, but why are you using `==` to check if Car objects are equal??

Comment: This was the solutions that my teacher gave me. And im trying to figure out the purpose of the nested for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have an array with 5 cars: `[Car1, Car2, Car3, Car4, Car5]`, and you call the method `driveOut(Car3)`.

By setting the value to null when you find it, you end up with `[Car1, Car2, null, Car4, Car5]`.  This practice can lead to `NullPointerException` type errors, because `null` values are in the middle of the array, and the data is not compacted.

The solution is basically eliminating the gap by starting from that point and shifting the remaining cars to the left:

```
Inner loop rev 1: [Car1, Car2, Car4, Car4, Car5]
Inner loop rev 2: [Car1, Car2, Car4, Car5, Car5]
```

Then outside the loop, the last entry is set to null, leaving you with `[Car1, Car2, Car4, Car5, null]`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the solution you're looking at is intended to move all of the non-null values to the left, rather than leaving the nulls in the middle of the array, which is what your suggestion would do.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate this a little bit? Because when I just set the carspaked[i]=null it gave me nullpointerexception when i tried to print them out. I guess he was trying to avoid this but I don't understand how that is doing it

Comment: It really depends on what you were doing to print them out, but nevertheless your solution could e.g. end up with car, null, car instead of car, car, null, which looks like what your teacher's solution wanted.

Comment: @Aaron - Your teacher is simply compacting all remaining parked cars in the beginning of the carsParked array. If you don't compact them and you loop through the array to print out the cars, you will need to check for NULL to see if a car is actually parked there before you print it out.

Answer (score 0):

what you're doing is called a nested loop.  for example

```
for(num2 = 0; num2 <= 3;  num2++)
{
    for(num1 = 0; num1 <= 2; num1++)
    {
        System.out.println(num2 + "   " + num1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that it's a nested loop

Comment: I thought you were asking "I don't know why he has two for loops"... I guess I didn't understand your question than.  can you please clarify what you're trying to figure out?

Comment: Yes sorry checl my comment above